# Grant Authorization to users with LDAP Authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, authorization, oracle-apex

***I've set up an LDAP Directory Authentication Scheme on Oracle Apex (v21.1) like this, and created the ACL on my Database:***

[image: authentication scheme]

If I try to test the LDAP Login, it's working (using my firstname.lastname). I replaced the IP Address and the domain name for confidential purposes.

I can connet to my application, but I cannot access it, I can't land on the home page, because I need an authorization scheme based on the groups the users are in.

In my company, there are multipled departements, they each have a group in the Microsoft Active Directory that will give them the access to the application, each groups are named like this: GRP_Inventaire_Dpt1, GRP_Inventaire_Dpt2, GRP_Inventaire_Dpt3,....

***I tried to create an Authorization Scheme based on this tutorial:***
https://blog.jonas-hellmann.de/authorization-in-oracle-apex-with-ldap-groups/

I tried to adapt the code of the function as you can see on the chapter 2.3 of the tutorial, ***here's how I did:***

[image: function for authorization]

***And here's my authorization scheme:***

[image: authorization scheme]

As you can see on the screen, I have to write the exact group name to access to my application, but I would like to have the possiblity to check if the user is in a group which start with "GRP_Inventaire_", no matter what department he is.

Unfortunately, some things seems already weird. Why does the password need to be statically written down in the function? How can dynamically have it in the function based on the LDAP Authentication Scheme? However, I know that I can use the p_username parameter for the username.

***Finally, if I try to connect to my application, I have the error message of my Authorization scheme: ***

[image: error message]

To summarize what I'm looking for:

- Authorization scheme based on the user logging in
- Check if the user is part of a group which start with "GRP_Inventaire_"
- The function needs to have dynamically the credentials of the user connecting

Do not hesitate to ask questions for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to check user's security group with something like this?

```
DECLARE VAL BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  VAL := APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP('xxx');
RETURN VAL;
END;
```

Comment: Hello, this is not working because it is checking the groups from the Apex Workspace. Since I am using an LDAP Authentication, I have to use the APEX_LDAP package functions to access to the groups information in the Active Directory : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_LDAP.html#GUID-0BE5C87B-BF08-4B80-BA42-5A08CE5923AC